# Deconstructs an array field ($unwind) with spark-mongo connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I´m trying to do queries with spark-mongo connector, a simple query like:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT members.name FROM members WHERE age >= 100")

Mike
Peter
...
```

but when I try to show a string-array (members.child_names) it does not execute $unwind, it generates a chain of Strings:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT members.child_names FROM members WHERE age >= 100")
Mike_child, Peter_child...
```

Is it possible project that query doing $unwind ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always explode it:

```
sqlContext.sql("""
  SELECT EXPLODE(members.child_names) FROM members WHERE age >= 100
""")
```